# Bash autocomplete: does not list files or directories

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In my bash terminal, I would usually press tab twice to get the file and folder list. 
For instance `cat` 2X<kbd>TAB</kbd> would list all files and folders in the present directory and `cd Proj`2X<kbd>TAB</kbd> would list all the directories starting with "Proj".

I do not see this behaviour (of listing files and directories on double <kbd>TAB</kbd> on a new machine (where I do not have root access). Instead  double <kbd>TAB</kbd> and subsequent <kbd>TAB</kbd>s cycles through the list of files or directories.  This is problematic because there are a lot of files in the directory and directory structure is very deep; thus, I can not use `ls` to list files every time.

Comment: Are you sure you're using bash on that new machine?

Comment: Yes.  I checked using `ps -p $$`

Comment: What's your bash version? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
bind 'TAB:complete'
```

or

```
bind '"\t":complete'
```

Comment: Tried didn't work

Comment: @zimbra314: I've updated my answer.

Comment: The second option worked in my case.

Comment: The sake of completeness: If you want your old Windows cmd.exe style back again: `bind '"\t":menu-complete'`

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by a setting within `readline` autocompletion. If you look at the [man page for bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) and search for "*Completing*" you'll see the configuration settings `complete`, `possible-completions` and `menu-complete`. These can be declared system-wide in `/etc/inputrc`, and optionally overridden per-user in `$HOME/.inputrc`.

In your `$HOME/.inputrc` add this line, creating the file if necessary:

```
"\C-i": complete
```

(include the double quotes and the backslash). Restart bash and you will have your TAB key working as you want, again.